# Rails Console not allowing me to create a record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't seem to create an object in the seed file for Employee. When I use Rails Console, it won't let me:

```
irb(main):003:0> Employee.create(id: 1, user_name: "exampleemployee", passcode: "2345", password: "987654321")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Employee Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "employees"  WHERE "employees"."user_name" = 'exampleemployee' LIMIT 1
  Employee Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "employees"  WHERE "employees"."passcode" = '2345' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Employee id: 1, user_name: "exampleemployee", passcode: "2345", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$7lpLZzAAJ5LsYLa/uKmfheyST3vfq7GY9hpoXVNECdL...">
irb(main):004:0> Employee.all
  Employee Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):005:0>
```

When I do it from my app on my localhost:3000, it creates the Employee and works.

Troubleshooting steps i've taken: reset the database, and re-seeded the file and same thing happens. I'm using Postgresql. I'm using bcrypt just for the password, could that be whats causing the issue?

I have an Employee model with the following validations:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password

  validates_presence_of :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :passcode
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, :passcode
  validates :passcode, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
  validates_length_of :passcode, is: 4
  validates_length_of :user_name, :password, minimum: 4
end
```

My schema for Employee:

```
  create_table "employees", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "passcode"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `password` instead of `password_digest` on create:

```
Employee.create(id: 1, user_name: "exampleemployee", passcode: "1234", password: "123456789",  password_confirmation: "123456789")
```

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

Comment: You are a genius haha. Thanks, totally knew there was some small mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Ah that didn't work! i'll edit what happened on the post

Comment: You're validating the presence of `password_confirmation` on the model, so you must pass it on create too. I'll edit my answer.